# Código para hacer un bloque anónimo

Tags: plsql

Tengo las siguientes lineas

```
SELECT UPPER(description)
 --INTO v_var
 FROM E_FND_LOOKUP_VALUES
 WHERE lookup_type = 'XBOL_OIC_OI_GF_GRUPO_FUNCIONAL'
 --AND UPPER(description) = UPPER(p_valor)
 AND LANGUAGE = 'ESA'
 AND enabled_flag = 'Y'
 AND NVL(end_date_active, SYSDATE) >= SYSDATE;
```

¿Cómo las paso para generar un `bloque anónimo` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  v_var <tipo> := <valor inicial>;
  p_valor <tipo> := <valor inicial>;
BEGIN
  <tu codigo>
END;
```